# Regex in :where clause Congomongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, clojure, congomongo

I am trying to query Mongodb for documents containing part of title that is passed through form.

```
(defn findmovie
 "Find movie by query"
 [query]
 (def search (str "#.*" (url-decode query) ".*"))
 (println search)
 (def movies (m/fetch :movie :where {:name {:$regex search}}))
 (println movies)
 (returnall movies)
)
```

`query` here is a parameter. Above code returns empty collection `()` no matter what I type in.

Example value for `:name` is `Gladiator (2000)` and `:name` in `:where` is something like `#.*gladiator.*`

Comment: Side note: You should not use `def` inside a function. Use `let` instead.

Comment: What do the values in the `:name` field look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the regular expression directly:

```
(defn findmovie
  "Find movie by query"
  [query]
  (let [search (re-pattern (str ".*" (url-decode query) ".*"))
        movies (m/fetch :movie :where {:name search})]
    (returnall movies)))
```

Comment: Thanks once again. It works. I have only added `(?i)` to the begining of pattern to make it case insensitive.